# how to comapare single object in listItem1 to customersList.if same id it will perform update operation otherwise insertion operation

Tags: spring-mvc

in my controller class this is my logic.

```
for (Customer listItem1 : customerList) {
    System.out.println(listItem1);
    customerList1=  customerService.getCustomerList();
    if(listItem1.CompareTo(customerList1)){
       customerService.updateCustomer(listItem1);
    }
    else{
        customerService.insertCustomer(listItem1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `instanceof` instead of `CompareTo` like so:

```
if(listItem1 instanceof customerList1) {
    //your code
} else {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.